# Rectangular selection for component designator in altium

Tags: pcb-design, components, altium

I noticed that is not possible to use rectangular selection for designator in Altium (PCB view). I have to select them by clicking on each of them. 
And for moving a group of them I can't use keyboard shortcut.

I understand that designator is not a object by itself but is attached to a component (unlike the text objet)

but there is a way to rectangular select on a group of designator and change value of them ?

EDIT :
Partially found a way. Go to top layer, select the component via rectangular selection (with component filter activated), then, click on the blue text "Designator" for all selected component. It select the corresponding component's designators.

Answer (score 2):

Just hold CTRL when dragging your rectangular selection (The Selection Filter needs 'Texts' to be enabled).

Comment: Very useful. Thanks for sharing this tip !

Answer (score 0):

1. select the layer of the Designator. For example top Overlay
2. Press Shift + s to select single layer mode. (one to three times)
3. now select the designators to move it. (As long as the designators position is not locked)

Comment: I'm looking for easy way to select MULTIPLES designator at once. You answer as nothing to do with that.